# How to get Object.keys iterating through object of arrays to wait for async fetched api results at the end of each iteration?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, async-await, es6-promise

This node code

1. reads in some local data
   `fs.readFile('./local.json', 'utf8', (err, data) => {`
2. Opens up a try `{`
3. Parses the data, then flattens it a little, `const json_data = JSON.parse(data);`
4. Loops through the resulting arrays and gathers data points
5. In the loop, code extracts urls and sends out two api requests for every iteration
6. The api requests are chained promises that return json
7. Returned data are checked and processed
8. During each iteration of the loop, data from the 3 sources are selected with ternary operators and conditions
9. Then string literals are composed using the preferred data points
10. At the and of fetch promise chain, right before the next iteration of the loop, the properly composed string literals are printed to a file
11. Only they are not properly composed...
12. The loop doesn't know enough enough to wait for promises to resolve, so data from the first iteration gets written to subsequent iterations
13. There is some code not shown here, for example assisting function and variable definitions, string literals, and catch blocks, but this is more or less the structure:

```
fs.readFile('./local.json', 'utf8', (err, data) => {
  try {
    // parse data and extract api endpoints
    const process_local_data = JSON.parse(data);

    //define functions and variables
    const functions_to_check_and_process_local_data = (data) => { //...
    }
    const functions_to_check_and_process_api_data = (data) => { //...
    }

    //define first api fetcher
    const first_api_fetcher = async(urla, urlb) => {
      const contentType = response.headers.get("content-type");
      const response = await fetch(urla);

      if (contentType && contentType.indexOf("application/json") !== -1) {
        let results = await response.json();
        functions_to_check_and_process_api_data(results);
      }

      await second_api_checker(urlb); //the second api request is chained to a promise in the first one

    } //end first api fetcher


    //define_second_api_fetcher
    const second_api_fetcher = async(url) => {
      const contentType = response.headers.get("content-type");
      const response = await fetch(url);

      if (contentType && contentType.indexOf("application/json") !== -1) {
        let results = await response.json();
        functions_to_check_and_process_api_data(results);
      }

    } //end second api checker

    //run the processing loop

    Object.keys(processed_local_json).forEach(item => {
      //check, process local data, and extract urls
      functions_to_check_and_process_local_data(item);
      //processed_local_json['item'];

      //define data processing function, that waits on first_api_fetcher (which waits on second api fetcher)
      const processData = async() => {
        await first_api_fetcher(url1, url2).then(
          //select whichever data is best and write to string literals
          //join string literals into an array
          //return array of string literals
        ) //end then 
      } //end processData
      //print string template literals to file (waits on processData)
      const printFile = async() => {
        const printData = await processData();
        //print to file
        fs.appendFile("file", printData, (err) => {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
          } else {
            console.log('wrote strings template literals to file');
          }
        }); //end write output to file
      } //end printfile

      //call function to trigger api requests, data processing, and string template literal composition
      printFile();
    }); //end Object.keys processing loop
  } //end try/catch
}) //end readfile
```

The code isn't perfect, but except for the major flaw, i.e. that the object.keys loop doesn't wait on the api fetches, it gets the job done.

It has a .then() in the processing function just to make it clear (to me) that processing happens after api fetches, however variables are initialized in scope outside the loop, so it doesn't seem necessary to return an array of values from the api_fetchers

Does anyone know how to get `Object.keys` loop to wait on api results at end of each iteration? Is there some boolian to set to send compiler back to beginning of loop until it's toggled with returned api data?

Or is there some trick to this I just missed in the docs?

Comment: What is `processed_local_json`?

Comment: You need to put all your promises in an array, and then call `Promise.all()` at the end of the loop to wait for them all.

Comment: You never call `processData()`

Comment: processed_local_json is `process_local_data` after it's been processed further, basically arrays of arrays of data. `processData()` gets called with an await in printFile(). Thanks, I'll test that out now

Comment: Sorry, missed that. So you need to use `await printFile()` or put all the promises returned by `printFile` into an array and wait for it with `Promise.all()`

Answer (score 0):

One side note: in the object.keys loop you define some async functions. I wouldn’t recommended defining them on each loop! They should be setup outside the loop.

As for “getting the loop to wait”… it’s important to understand conceptually that you don’t get the loop itself to wait, per se..that object.keys line of code is synchronous code. Maybe you knew that but just want to be clear.

When you invoke asynchronous code within that loop (printfile function), you will fire off multiple asynchronous printfile functions, unless you await the asynchronous function invocation itself. That’s how you can force the loop to stop further processing until each invokation completes.

Comment: It sounds like you are saying take processData out of the Object.keys loop and and add an await to printFile, unless you mean Object.keys itself needs to be called in an async file, either way, thanks, still wrapping my head around keeping track of async/await

Comment: Yes on the first point… you are defining processData there, not invoking it. Functions rarely ought to be defined in a loop that uses them. On 2nd point, if printFile is async it returns a promise and needs to be awaited if you want it to stop on each invokation in the loop. Just because it awaits prcocessData internally, doesn’t make it a synchronous function. Think of ‘await’ as a way to make asynchronous code stop until it’s done before going to the next line.

Comment: Oh, and about object.keys..it’s like any other for loop..it’s synchronous. You cant stop it.. that line..from behaving differently.

Comment: Both answers were good, but I'm accepting this one because my preference is to add `await` to printFile and async to Object.keys, rather than collecting promises into an array and waiting with Promise.all(). The solution was: `await printFile();` inside of  `Object.keys(processed_local_json).forEach( async (item) => {});`

Comment: actually it's still buggy, spoke too soon

Comment: In that last part, you’re making your loop fire off multiple asynchronous functions (think multiple things firing off in parallel, which run at their own pace) on each invokation of the loop. However your goal, I believe, was to figure out how to prevent one loop from starting until the other finishes, because of some dependencies on each iteration. I.e. it’s not helping your goal to call an async function in object.keys.

Comment: It could have been done without fetch, maybe with a library like `XMLHttpRequest`, but using await/async is forward looking. You're right, I want those functions in series, but `promise.all` wouldn't pass data between them. The solution was to enclose every operation in an object returning function, then pass and combine ... those objects between chained promises. `Async` in `object.keys` worked, but I think a `for loop` would have worked also. The promise chain works perfectly, thanks to Tamas Polgar https://medium.com/developer-rants/javascript-promise-chain-passing-down-data-d7bdcc7ff49e